# 'fullName' form control does not change during text input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups, angular-formbuilder, controlvalueaccessor

I'm working on `ControlValueAccessor` implementation in a child form. I have a parent form group and control as following

```js
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      user: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-custom-input formControlName="user"></app-custom-input>

  {{ form.get('user').value | json }}
</form>
```

And the child form

```js
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  userInfo: FormGroup;

  onChange  = (value) => {};

  onTouched = (value) => {};

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userInfo = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  writeValue(value): void {
    console.log(value)
    value && this.userInfo.setValue(value, {emitEvent: false});
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    console.log("on change");
    this.userInfo.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    console.log("on touched");
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="userInfo">
  <label>Full name</label>
  <input forControlName="fullName" type="text" name="fullName" />

  <label>Email</label>
  <input formControlName="email" type="email" />
</ng-container>
```

I have the following result:
[image]

The value can be displayed just for the `email` form control and updated on its change, but the `fullName` sill the same during typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its should be 'formControlName' instead of

```
<input forControlName="fullName" type="text" name="fullName" />
```

Comment: I left the input with just `forControlName="fullName"` but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnpzdb
i dont get it, i mean you mistyping.